# Can't scroll the view when the view is in position absolute in ReactNative how to scroll the view when the view is in position absolute in reactnative

Tags: react-native, scrollview, absolute

Can't scroll the view when the view is in position absolute in ReactNative how to scroll the view when the view is in position absolute in react-native.

```
<View style={{position:'absolute'}}>
    <View>
    <ScrollView>
        <View>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff",height:100}}>Kaushal</Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Could you set a height in ScrollView style and test this way? in this way: `<ScrollView style={{ height: '200px' }} >`

Comment: Or other option is using a View that wrap ScrollView, in this way: `<View style={{ position: 'relative', flex:1 }}`><ScrollView>...</ScrollView></View>`. Could you test this too?

Comment: ok, I will check and let you know.